# Rolling back conda revision that contains unmaintained packages

Tags: conda

I wanted to roll the conda back to several tens of transactions earlier. To do this, I tried `conda install --revision 70` (`-c conda-forge`). It did not work with the following error.

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - conda-forge/linux-64::ipython==7.19.0=py38h81c977d_0
```

A little bit of research showed that this is actually because that version of the `ipython` is [removed from the repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10460).

Still, I need to roll back my environment. Ideally, I want to roll back with that specific package replaced with slightly newer one. How could this be possible, without having to trace every single transaction manually from current environment info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pointed out in the thread](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10460#issuecomment-771044246), that build is marked as `broken`. This is a special label that Conda defaults to not searching. However, one can override this, but one needs to ensure that the non-`broken` versions are still preferred.

Something like:

```
conda install --revision 70 -c conda-forge -c defaults -c conda-forge/label/broken
```

If there are any other channels you use, they should also be listed *prior* to the `conda-forge/label/broken`. Also, `channel_priority` configuration option must be `"flexible"`, otherwise the higher priority channels mask the lower priority ones.